# Compare values of timestamps and assign a value to each of them in case they have changed

Tags: mysql, sql

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=47d82e5449909b497ced26dd162e60ad)**

```
CREATE TABLE operations (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    time_stamp DATE,
    product VARCHAR(255),
    plan_week VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO operations (time_stamp, product, plan_week)
VALUES 
("2020-01-01", "Product_A", "CW01"),
("2020-01-01", "Product_B", "CW01"),
("2020-01-01", "Product_C", "CW01"),

("2020-03-15", "Product_A", "CW01"),
("2020-03-15", "Product_B", "CW02"),
("2020-03-15", "Product_C", "CW02"),
("2020-03-15", "Product_D", "CW01");
```

**Expected Result:**

```
    time_stamp   |   product     |   plan_week   |   week_switch
  ---------------|---------------|---------------|----------------- 
    2020-01-01   |   Product_A   |     CW01      |       no
    2020-01-01   |   Product_B   |     CW01      |       yes
    2020-01-01   |   Product_C   |     CW01      |       yes
                 |               |               |
    2020-03-15   |   Product_A   |     CW01      |       no
    2020-03-15   |   Product_B   |     CW02      |       yes
    2020-03-15   |   Product_C   |     CW02      |       yes
    2020-03-15   |   Product_D   |     CW01      |       no
```

In the above result I want to list all `products` from the table and compare the two `time_stamps` to each other. 
If the `plan_week` of one product has switched between the both `time_stamps` I want that in the additional column called `week_switch` the word `yes` gets inserted and if not the word `no` gets inserted.

I tried to go with this query but could not make it work:

```
SELECT time_stamp, product, plan_week,
        (CASE WHEN MIN(plan_week) <> MAX(plan_week) THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END) AS week_switch
FROM operations
GROUP BY 1,2;
```

What do I need to change to get the expected result?

Comment: You've aked this question (with tiny variations) 4 or 5 times by now. I'm not criticising the format or validity of the question, but at some point, you have try to figuring these things out from what you've learned here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just use window functions:

```
select o.*,
       (case when min(plan_week) over (partition by product) = max(plan_week) over (partition by product)
             then 'no' else 'yes'
        end) as switched
from operations o;
```

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=5ef69ea19f9edcc47242484dd3abc614

Comment: Just for my own documenation: Full comparison of two time-stamps: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=2b0cb57fe9d281ded9b8bce22c7e1bde

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirement correctly, your `week_switch` result row depends on just your product, not its timestamp.

So compute it in a subquery.

```
  SELECT product,
         (CASE 
          WHEN MIN(plan_week) <> MAX(plan_week) THEN 'yes' 
          ELSE 'no' END)  AS week_switch
    FROM operations
   GROUP BY product
```

Then JOIN that subquery to your details ([fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=bf2581f41c08b951aee38967db051970)).

```
WITH switched AS (
  SELECT product,
         CASE
         WHEN MIN(plan_week) <> MAX(plan_week) THEN 'yes'
         ELSE 'no' END AS week_switch
    FROM operations
   GROUP BY product
)
SELECT
operations.time_stamp,
operations.product,
operations.plan_week,
switched.week_switch
FROM operations
LEFT JOIN switched ON operations.product = switched.product
WHERE time_stamp in ('2020-01-01', '2020-03-15')
GROUP BY 1,2;
```